Getting Gradle handshake_failure error on new installation
I have a new user on our system. He is trying to build the software for the first time, and is getting the following error.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: 
A problem occured configuring root project 'project_name'
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.6.6.
      > Could not GET 'https://{url}/nexus/content/groups/public-maven/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.6.6/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.6.6.pom'
          > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs/gradle/org/6.8.3/userguide/build_environment/html#gradle_system_properties
              > Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

No one else on the project is getting this error. He has the same cacert as everyone else. He is using the same TLS version as everyone else.
Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Check java version and gradle version

Is your java version upto date? Check your firewall settings to make sure it allows requests made to gradle.
Run ./gradlew clean and try again

./gradlew clean gets the same result as build.

@VultureMF did you see if the user is behind a firewall/proxy with enough permissions? The cacert can be same, permissions might be another thing. Also try using --debug flag for gradle to see the debug logs for gradle

In my opinion your answer is really a comment and not an answer. Please earn the comment privilege and don't post comments as answers. Especially not after the OP has stated that your suggestion did not resolve their problem. And what exactly do you mean by Is your java version upto date? A new Java version is released every six months. Do you mean the last released Java version?

The solution was to add gradle.properties to the ~/.gradle directory with the truststore and keystore defined in them, as below.
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=path.to.cacert.jks
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keystore=path.to.user.keystore.jks
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit

